# Angular 4 How to read the token in the header?

Tags: angular

I am new to angular. I can not read the token (jwt) in the REST service response header. How can I read headers? this is my code:

```
    loginUser(loginUser:Login,callback: (data) => void){ 

        let body = JSON.stringify(loginUser)
        const headerJson = {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'    
        }
        let options = { headers: new HttpHeaders( headerJson ) };
        return this.http.post(this.config.datiBean.urlLoginToken, body,options).subscribe(

          res =>{

            console.log("body :"+JSON.stringify(res)); //ok

            callback(res);
          }

          /// at this point how can I read headers?

        )};
}
```

I would like to read this information:
[image]

thanks for your help

Comment: Have a look at https://angular.io/guide/http it mentions how you would read the response.

Comment: { observe: 'response' }

Comment: if I insert return this.http.post (this.config.datiBean.urlLoginToken, body, {observe: "response"}). subscribe (..... I get the following error from server 415 (Unsupported Media Type) because the server receives only json calls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely my method was not correct. I modified my method this way:

```
    loginUser(loginUser:Login,callback: (data) => void){ 

       let creds = JSON.stringify(loginUser);
       let contentHeader = new HttpHeaders({ "Content-Type":"application/json" });
       this.http.post(this.config.datiBean.urlLoginToken, creds, { headers: contentHeader, observe: 'response' })
        .subscribe(
        (resp) => {
            console.log("TOKEN:  "+resp.headers.get('X-Auth'))
            console.log("body:  "+JSON.stringify(resp.body))
            callback(resp)
        },
        (resp) => {
            console.log("resp-error");
            console.log(resp);
        }
      );
  };
```

Now it works correctly

Answer (score 0):

Diego.

If you are using the NG4 and the now deprecated http class then I think you should try to collect the keys and values inside the subscription.
https://v4.angular.io/api/http/Headers#values

But consider that you will only be able to use the headers that are exposed. You can include the list of those using the [Access-Control-Expose-Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers).

```
res =>{
  console.log("body :"+JSON.stringify(res)); //ok
  callback(res);
  headerKeys = res.headers.keys(); // this will provide an array of strings for the exposed headers
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if you are trying to use the header values outside the subscription, in that case as I put on the code you can create a variable outside the subscription and assign the values inside with the res.headers. Anyway you have to specify the x-Auth in the access-control-expose-header in order to be able to collect the information. I am going to try to provide a better example of the code.