# Angular 9 On Page load read custom response header

Tags: angular, response-headers

I have a scenario where I have to extract/read custom response header before component loads? App is hosted on Apache server which is setting current logged in user in response header (as it is configured for pass through authentication). To authorize the user first, i need to validate it during pre-render phase based on which user would either see requested page or error page if not authorized.

This may not be preferred way of authorizing, but the current setup is not providing much option without implementing new written security framework.

[SS of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjYAP.png)

Comment: Probably this way: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48783332/533711

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As per the link you provided, here I am not making any API calls for which I can subscribe to response data. I need to intercept response when the user clicks on the link & page is served from server. With the help of route guards, I want to look for custom response header. I tried using HttpInterceptor but subscribing to it requires passing HttpRequest object. Not sure how to get that. I am still not able to find the solution.

Comment: route guards are not what you are looking for. They run on the front end. You are trying to enforce authorization which is a back end task.

Comment: @ente correct. But the question still remains open. How can i extract custom response header before the page loads?

Comment: Can you provide the code in which you send request?

Comment: Code is very basic that routes the user to the landing page upon clicking the link. I want to extend it so that I can read the custom response header when the page loads and validate the value from back end API and do conditional routing.It will be great if someone can answer.

Comment: Folks, I am still waiting for answer. Please point me to resource where I can find on how to intercept response headers for a component.